# Charts from numbers not dynamically updating in Pages/Keynote

Tags: macos, numbers, pages, keynote, iwork

I have the 2015 versions of Pages, Numbers, and Keynote on Yosemite.

I created a chart in numbers and then copied it to Pages or Keynote.
I then want to be able to change the data in Numbers and see the chart updated in Pages or Keyonte. However, I don't see an option to "refresh".

Is there a way to dynamically link Numbers to Pages or Keynote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html

However, a month after this question was asked, Sal Soghoian - then the Product Manager for Automation Technologies at Apple got on stage to demonstrate how to automate placement of a numbers chart inside a keynote presentation. This should be easy to automate following the video and slides.

- https://developer.apple.com/wwdc15/306

Comment: How sad, I was afraid of this. Feedback sumbitted.